# facebook share button does not show the description which has been defined

Tags: facebook, button, share

I have got a  problem with facebook share button on my page. the following page have got dynamic content which is changed by ID which is called from database.

I have followed all codes which has been mentioned on facebook but on preview page before sharing, the first "p" content is shown not the description and title which have been defined.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.shalman-seven.co.uk/index.php?page=RoozportalNews&ID=<?php echo $ID; ?>/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.shalman-seven.co.uk/Images/Background.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $cat_sql_row['title']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $cat_sql_row['summary']; ?>" />

<p class="shareIcons"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.shalman-seven.co.uk/index.php?page=RoozportalNews&ID=<?php echo $ID; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" class="sharebutton" style="color:rgb(12, 69, 90);"></i></a></p>
```

for example you can see it on :

http://www.shalman-seven.co.uk/index.php?page=RoozportalNews&ID=2

thank you for your help.

Comment: <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.shalman-seven.co.uk/index.php?page=RoozportalNews&ID=<?php echo $ID; ?>/" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.shalman-seven.co.uk/Images/Background.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $cat_sql_row['title']; ?>" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $cat_sql_row['summary']; ?>" />

Comment: <p class="shareIcons"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.shalman-seven.co.uk/index.php?page=RoozportalNews&ID=<?php echo $ID; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" class="sharebutton" style="color:rgb(12, 69, 90);"></i></a></p>